# Nancy Module Unit Testing. Exception in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, liquid, nancy

Can't find reason why test isn't work. Has anybody known why it happen? Difference between these two tests is ony in views. In first it is ".html" page and in second it is ".liquid". In my project I use ".liquid", so ".html" is only for testing correct working test.
I have a Nancy Module

```
public sealed class Module : NancyModule
{
    public Module(IBackend storage)
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => View["Create.liquid"];     
        Get["/Test"] = _ => View["TestHtml.html"];
    }
}
```

And the tests

```
[Test]
public void test_html()
{
    // Given
    var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with =>
    {
        var module = new Module(new Endpoint());
        with.Module(module);
    });
    browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

    // When
    var result = browser.Get("/Test", with =>
    {
        with.HttpRequest();
    });

    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
}

[Test]
public void test_liquid()
{
    // Given
    var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with =>
    {
        var module = new Module(new Endpoint());
        with.Module(module);
    });
    browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

    // When
    var result = browser.Get("/", with =>
    {
        with.HttpRequest();
    });

    // Then
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
}
```

There is exception on second test

```
System.Exception : ConfigurableBootstrapper Exception
----> Nancy.RequestExecutionException : Oh noes!
----> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException : Unable to locate view 'Create.liquid'
Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm
Locations inspected: ,,,,,,,,views/Module/Create.liquid-en-    US,views/Module/Create.liquid,Module/Create.liquid-en-US,Module/Create.liquid,views/Create.liquid-en-US,views/Create.liquid,Create.liquid-en-US,Create.liquid
Root path: D:\Projects\epm-vsp-pasta\Tests\bin\Debug
```

With Stack Trace

```
at Nancy.Testing.PassThroughStatusCodeHandler.Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy.Testing\PassThroughStatusHandler.cs: line 22
at Nancy.NancyEngine.CheckStatusCodeHandler(NancyContext context) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy\NancyEngine.cs: line 219
at Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequest(Request request, Func`2 preRequest) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy\NancyEngine.cs: line 112
at Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequest(Request request) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy\NancyEngine.cs: line 77
at Nancy.Testing.Browser.HandleRequest(String method, String path, Action`1 browserContext) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy.Testing\Browser.cs: line 125
at Nancy.Testing.Browser.Get(String path, Action`1 browserContext) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy.Testing\Browser.cs: line 62
at Tests.TestModule.test_liquid() in TestModule.cs: line 111 --RequestExecutionException
at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex) in d:\Nancy-master\src\Nancy\NancyEngine.cs: line 272
--ViewNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with .NET assembly loading. Since no types in the Nancy.ViewEngines.Dotliquid assembly is directly used, the .NET compiler thinks it can be smart and not include the reference in the assembly meta data. This results in the assembly not being loaded into the application domain, at all, during run time.

The reason it works for .html files is that the SuperSimpleViewEngine, that manages .html extensions, is built into Nancy.dll and that is loaded.

You can work around this by explicitly using a type from the assembly, for example putting something like `var foo = typeof(DotLiquidViewEngine)` in your test code, of by using the `ViewEngine<DotLiquidViewEngine>()` property on the configurable bootstrapper setup.

For our next release, 0.17, we have added code to reduce this effect, as much as possible, by scanning the assemblies in your "bin"-folder and explicitly loading any that references a Nancy* assembly.

Hope this helps

Comment: I do what you advise me, but now all my test failed with this exception System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Nancy.IStaticContentProvider' from assembly 'Nancy, Version=0.16.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't referenced the liquid view engine from your test project:

> Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm

Comment: But my test html page located in the same folder as all liquid views. And I get it from my test without any problem...Or I didn't understand you?

Comment: You didn't understand me. You need to add a reference to the liquid assembly or add the nuget for it to your test project.

Comment: Like in 1 answer? I added DotLiquid and Nancy.ViewEngines.DotLiquid assembles to my Test project and did what he talking in first answer, but unfortunately all tests failed with those exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this occur if the page isn't copied to the output directory.

i.e. check the properties for the .liquid file in Visual Studio and ensure it has the same 'Copy to Output Directory' setting as the working .html file.